# Regex check previous line

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Using regex (in c#.net) is it possible to check the previous line of a string?

For instance, I need to select strings in which the previous line is not a series of asterisks (prev line:`******`)

Comment: What if there are two lines in row that contain nothing but asterisks? Do you want to select the first one?

Answer (score 6):

```
(?m)^(?<!^\*+\r?\n).+
```

`(?m)` turns on multiline mode so `^` can match the beginning of a line. The lookbehind checks the previous line; if it succeeds (that is, it *doesn't* see a line of asterisks), `.+` consumes the current line.

Comment: Old Macs use just `\r` for a newline.  Perhaps the `\n` should be optional?

Comment: They can't both be optional; to match exactly one of any of the three kinds of separator you need something like `\r?\n|\r`. I suppose we should keep doing it that way, but I hardly ever saw `\r` in the wild even before they made the switch.

Comment: Oh, I didn't look at your regex closely enough. They could both be optional if they followed a `$`. So something like this: `$\r?\n?`.  But you're right, that is a pretty obscure case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RegexOptions.MultiLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) and then match something like the following:

```
(?<!^\*+$\r?\n?.*)foo
```

This matches "foo" only if the previous line doesn't consist of asterisks.