# C# Regex, Check previous line for subpattern THEN continue matching only if subpattern matches on the left of the same line

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to exclude lines that have a "#-hide-" comment on the previous line which i can do with a modification of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728522/regex-check-previous-line) script:

```
(?m)^(?<!^#-hide-\r?\n).+
```

And I also want to match the text between "`func\s+`" and "`s*\(`"
(i.e. matching only *"function_name"* out of *"func function_name():"*)

This works with:

```
(?<=func\s+).+(?=\s*\()
```

But trying to combine the two by doing `(?m)^(?<!^#-hide-\r?\n)(?<=func\s+).+(?=\s*\()` doesn't work.

---

overall:

```
func include_me():

#-hide-
func exclude_me():

func include_me2():
```

Should match "include_me" and "include_me2"

Comment: It's probably easier to read line-by-line. If a line starts with `#-hide-`, then throw that line and the next line away. If a line gets through that simple filter, then do whatever you want.  By the way, _exclude_ is the word you want, not _disclude_

Comment: Ah right, "disclude" isn't a word in this timeline.

Comment: Just trying to help. I'm a native English speaker, but I know enough to make glaring mistakes in another language

Comment: I'm not taking offense, I'm just joking that "disclude" could easily have become the norm. 
It's just something no one corrected me on and it sounded right in my head until now. So thanks.

(I looked it up and technically disclude is a word (or a somewhat common mistake) but it's not recognized by the English dictionary people or something so it's classified as "non-standard".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?m)(?<=(?<!^#-hide-[\r\n]+)func\s+).+?(?=\s*\()
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%28%3F%3C%3D%28%3F%3C!%5E%23-hide-%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2B%29func%5Cs%2B%29.%2B%3F%28%3F%3D%5Cs*%5C%28%29&i=func%20include_me%28%29%3A%0D%0A%0D%0A%23-hide-%0D%0Afunc%20disclude_me%28%29%3A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunc%20include_me2%28%29%3A). *Details*:

- `(?m)` - an inline `RegexOptions.Multiline` regex option
- `(?<=(?<!^#-hide-[\r\n]+)func\s+)` - a positive lookbehind that requires the following pattern to match immediately to the left of the current location:

  - `(?<!^#-hide-[\r\n]+)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is start of a line (`^`), `#-hide-` text and then one or more CR or LF chars (`[\r\n]+`)
  - `func\s+` - `func` and one or more whitespaces
- `.+?` - one or more chars other than LF chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\()` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more whitespace chars and then a `(` char immediately to the right of the current location.